# Install OpenCV macOS missing cv2.so

Tags: python, macos, opencv

I'm trying to install OpenCV3 in my mac following this tutorial "https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2016/12/05/macos-install-opencv-3-and-python-3-5/ " 
But after run "$ sudo make install" I should have a "cv2.cpython-35m-darwin.so" or a similar name that later I should change it to "cv2.so"
But the options that I have are this ones. Anyone know which of this files should a change to "cv2.so" ?

https://ibb.co/dTQOtm

Answer (score 0):

You can try `brew install opencv3`